# Possibilities on Google TV emulator

Tags: google-tv

Iam an android developer and wanted to know if someone has already started developing android apps for Google TV on its emulator. 
I have read the google's documents on Google TV and I have few of my thoughts revolving around my way . I wanna know which all capabilities does the Google Tv SDK gives us while working with Google TV emulator..

1. Does Live TV uses Activity or Fragments on top of which the **content(TV SHOWS)** is displayed ?
2. Can we control the Live TV feature provided by Google by customizing the Views of Live TV like placing a widget which shows the newly released movies on a timely basis?
3. Is Live TV only a native app provided by Google and doesn't offer any flexibility wherein we can **replace** the Live TV app by writing our own app which shows the same **content(TV SHOWS)** offered by Live TV ? (as we can modify default contacts app in our android mobile devices)

Please address my confusions !!

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no official way to have live tv participate with your apps.
2. You can change the channel of the TV using an intent from your app. (And find out about channels using the channel listing content provider.)
3. There is no supported way to do this.

Comment: Hi Les , Thanks for your response .. I have one more question against point 2 - Is Channel Listing Content provider depends on Internet or Dish TV inorder to provide the channel info?

Comment: The internet.  More characters to get past limit.

Comment: You can potentially use audio content recognition (ACR) to enable live TV to control/trigger an application.  I don't believe GTV has any support at this time though.  Yahoo ConnectedTV widgets will have this capability soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make any changes in with live tv thought apps. You can only change the programs not everything. If you Google want to change then they do it, because they have all rights of content. Now all the process are digitilaized. Why Google can made changes in it? Reason Firstly they will receive all the programs by channels after that they will upload on own server. After that send the signals to satellites and satellite send these signals to the users.